# WSClient Plugin Soap 1.2 Error

Tags: grails, groovyws

Environment: Grails-1.3.4, Ubuntu 9.10, Intellij 9.0.3, JVM 1.6

I'm getting the below stack trace using WSClient while trying to interact with a SOAP 1.2 server. I was able to get the [wsclient example application](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+WSClient+in+Grails) working. Changing the URL to the other server throws the exception during initialization. Any ideas?

I did see a reference to SOAP 1.2 in the documentation that suggested adding

```
proxy.setPreferredSoapVersion(SoapVersion.SOAP_1_2)
```

Which I did, but to no avail.

Thanks,
Steve

> 2010-10-19 10:53:42,787 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Only document-style SOAP 1.1 http are supported for auto-selection of endpoint; none were found.
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Only document-style SOAP 1.1 http are supported for auto-selection of endpoint; none were found.
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.findEndpoint(ClientImpl.java:212)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.(ClientImpl.java:151)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:253)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:196)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.dynamic.DynamicClientFactory.createClient(DynamicClientFactory.java:175)
>       at groovyx.net.ws.AbstractCXFWSClient.createClient(AbstractCXFWSClient.java:198)
>       at groovyx.net.ws.WSClient.initialize(WSClient.java:107)
>       at groovyx.net.ws.IWSClient$initialize.call(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading the source for WSClient from groovy, and debugging it.

if you installed ws-client using grails installer it will most likely be this code

http://svn.codehaus.org/gmod/groovyws/branches/0.5.1/